# Why do I lose css hover functionality on menu items after changing attributes with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a navigation menu which link css attributes I modify when clicking them. Also when I click on anything but the links they're css properties change as they should.

But before initiating the jquery the css psuedo `:hover` worked on the `.cmNavItem a:hover` worked fine but doesn't work after any of the jquery functions have run?

Here is my code:

```
<nav id="cmNavContainer"><!-- Start of side menu -->

    <ul id="cmNav">
        <li class="cmNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem1">link 1</a></li>
        <li class="cmNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem2">link 2</a></li>
        <li class="cmNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem3">link 3</a></li>
        <li class="cmNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem4">link 4</a></li>
        <li class="cmNavItem"><a href="#" id="navItem5">link 5</a></li>
    </ul>

</nav><!-- closes cmNav -->
```

css:

```
.cmNavItem a:link, .cmNavItem a:visited{
        border-bottom:1px solid #323233;
        border-top:1px solid #323233;
        line-height:30px;
        width:182px;
        display:block;
        margin-left:0;
        padding-left:10px;

        font-size:15px;
        font-family:arial,sans-serif;
        color:#fff;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
        .cmNavItem a:hover{
            border-bottom:1px solid #000;
            border-top:1px solid #2a2a2b;
        }
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".cmNavItem a").on('click', function(){
        $(this).css({
        'border-bottom-color':'000',
        'border-top-color': '2a2a2b',

        });
        $(this).css('opacity','1').closest('.cmNavItem').siblings('.cmNavItem').find('a').css({
        'opacity': '0.3',
        'border-bottom-color': '323233',
        'border-top-color': '323233'
        });


    });

    $("#cmNavContainer").animate({left: 0}, 1000);


    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
        if ( ! $(e.target).closest('.cmNavItem').length ) {
            // you clicked anywhere but on an element inside #linkitem (or itself)
            $('.cmNavItem a').css({
            'opacity': '2',
            'border-bottom-color': '323233',
            'border-top-color': '323233'

            });
        }
    });

});
```

What do i need to do to be able to have the css `:hover` work again after the jquery runs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMO the hover-effect still works.
By the way, the colors #000, #2a2a2a, #323232 may look pretty much the same at 1px line.
If I change the hover border-colors to something easier to see (lets say #0f0 and #f00) you can see the hovering.

```
http://jsfiddle .net/2qfQH/
```

Tested on FF 20, Opera 12, Chrome 26, IE 10